# Setting a variable to a parameter value inline when calling a function

Tags: python, assignment-operator, method-call

In other languages, like Java, you can do something like this:

```java
String path;
if (exists(path = "/some/path"))
    my_path = path;
```

the point being that `path` is being set as part of specifying a parameter to a method call.  I know that this doesn't work in Python. It is something that I've always wished Python had.

Is there any way to accomplish this in Python?  What I mean here by "accomplish" is to be able to write both the call to `exists` and the assignment to `path`, as a single statement with no prior supporting code being necessary.

I'll be OK with it if a way of doing this requires the use of an additional call to a function or method, including anything I might write myself.  I spent a little time trying to come up with such a module, but failed to come up with anything that was less ugly than just doing the assignment before calling the function.

UPDATE: @BrokenBenchmark's answer is perfect if one can assume Python 3.8 or better.  Unfortunately, I can't yet do that, so I'm still searching for a solution to this problem that will work with Python 3.7 and earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) if you're using Python 3.8 or above:

```py
import os
if os.path.isdir((path := "/some/path")):
    my_path = path
```

Comment: Nice!  Unfortunately though, my code can't yet assume 3.8+.  So I need to hold out for a solution that works with 3.7-.  But this IS exactly like what I'm looking for.   -   Oh, btw, why the extra parens?  I assume that those aren't necessary.

Comment: You're correct, the extra parens aren't needed in this case, but walrus is a little bit weird in terms of parsing, so it's often a good idea to include parens around it, especially in statements such as list comprehensions.

Comment: Cool.  I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I don't believe there's anything before Python 3.8, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something that has some issues, but does technically get me where I was looking to be.  Maybe someone else will have ideas for improving this to make it fully cool.  Here's what I have:

```
# In a utility module somewhere

def v(varname, arg=None):
    if arg is not None:
        if not hasattr(v, 'vals'):
            v.vals = {}
        v.vals[varname] = arg
    return v.vals[varname]

# At point of use

if os.path.exists(v('path1', os.path.expanduser('~/.harmony/mnt/fetch_devqa'))):
    fetch_devqa_path = v('path1')
```

As you can see, this fits my requirement of no extra lines of code.  The "variable" involved, `path1` in this example, is stored on the function that implements all of this, on a per-variable-name basis.

One can question if this is concise and readable enough to be worth the bother.  For me, the verdict is still out.  If not for the need to call the `v()` function a second time, I think I'd be good with it structurally.

The only functional problem I see with this is that it isn't thread-safe.  Two copies of the code could run concurrently and run into a race condition between the two calls to `v()`.  The same problem is greatly magnified if one fails to choose unique variable names every time this is used.  That's probably the deal killer here.

Can anyone see how to use this to get to a similar solution without the drawbacks?

Comment: The walrus operator (`:=`) is a much nicer solution imo

Comment: OP stated that they have a Python version earlier than 3.8, so the walrus operator is unfortunately off the table.

Comment: The assignment outside of the conditional adds at most one line of code, so in terms of cleanliness, the bar is pretty high.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark - agreed.   This isn't something I'll be using.  It would need to be a bit better than this.  Was hoping someone smarter than me could think of the final tweak to make this useful.

Comment: (note that I haven't accepted this as the correct answer :o) )